# Dynamic Arrays: Need help copying one array to another one

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to create a program that uses the 'new' operator to create a dynamic array in heap of the program. The program creates and populates its dynamic array one (int) elements at a time for each input data (cin).

Key parts.

1.) Program has to used "cin >>" for data input to accept on integer at a time until EOF is pressed on the keyboard (cntrl-z for windows).

2.) User input has to be tested using !cin.eof() && cin.good() to test whether or not the EOF key was pressed and if the data is valid. (kinda of confused about the cin.good() part).

3.) The program will create a series of longer and longer arrays to contain all previous elements and the current incoming one. Also, the program will delete the previous version of the array after completing the current version.

4.) The program also tests if heap memory has been exhausted after each use of the new operator. (need help with this)

I keep getting error message "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTOR After normal black (#146)" (visual studio). What's the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
 #include <iostream> 
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cassert>
    using namespace std;
    // main
    int main() {
        int size = 2;
        int * array1 = new int[size];
        int arrayInput;
        int count = 0;
            do {
                if (array1 != NULL) {
                    cout << "Enter an integer (EOF to stop): " << endl;
                    cin >> arrayInput;
                    if (size < count) {
                        int * tempArray;
                        tempArray = new int[size * 2];
                        if (tempArray != NULL)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                                array1[i] = tempArray[i];
                            }
                            delete[] array1;
                            array1 = tempArray;
                            size *= 2;
                            delete [] tempArray;
                        }
                        else
                            cout << "Insufficient Heap resource." << endl;  // If we get here the Heap is out of space
                    }
                    if (!cin.eof()) {
                        array1[count++] = arrayInput;
                    }
                }
                else
                    cout << "Insufficient Heap resource." << endl;  // If we get here the Heap is out of space
            } while (!cin.eof());
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                cout << array1[i] << endl;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `new` yourself, let `std::vector` do it properly instead!

Comment: Can't use a vector for this assignment. Professor wants us to use a regular array.

Comment: [Kick your teacher and learn c++ in first place.](http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2015/02/i-have-dream-im-dreaming-of-so-called-c.html)

Comment: @Sam `if (array1 != NULL)`  This can never happen with a compliant C++ compiler.  Didn't your professor who is so gung-ho on using `new[]` tell you that `new []` throws a `std::bad_alloc` on failure?

Answer (score 1):

```
                    tempArray = new int[size * 2];

                    if (tempArray != NULL)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            array1[i] = tempArray[i];
                        }
```

You allocate a new array twice as big as your old array. Then you copy the contents of the newly allocated array into your existing array. The newly-allocated array contains random garbage, that you just used to override the existing, good data, in your old array.

That's one obvious bug, but it won't explain the crash.

```
                        delete[] array1;
                        array1 = tempArray;
                        size *= 2;
                        delete [] tempArray;
```

After copying, you delete your old array. Then you also delete your new array, that you just allocated. That smells like another bug, but it still won't explain the crash.

```
                if (!cin.eof()) {
                    array1[count++] = arrayInput;
                }
```

Now, you can answer your own question here: what happens when you continue to write to a pointer that was pointing to memory that you freed, recently?

That are multiple bugs in the shown code. They all must be fixed. I haven't looked further, past this point. There might still be other issues with this code. A [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should be able to help you to find any remaining bugs in your program.

Comment: `if (tempArray != NULL)`  -- This won't happen with a compliant compiler.